# How does my Ruby on Rails application connect to database when using 'find_by' and similar methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, session, connection

I am optimizing Oracle database access in a Rails 3.2.2 application. I reduced the number of queries through `where` and `find_by` and other methods.

How can I check its effect on my database connections/sessions?

All of those queries were located near to one another in the code, and are pretty similar or even the same, so some data were surely extracted from the cache (`CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`).

Is my application doing a checkout/checking from the pool for every database query? How does it work?

Edit: since I did not write, nowhere in the code is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout` or
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin` used.

Comment: Are you looking for exactly what queries the server executed?

Comment: I am actually looking for an explanation how is my application opening a connection to db, is it for every query that I do in my code, or is it opening a connection for the first one and holding to it for a while?

Comment: I think you may be interested in [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool)
From what I see in the available methods, I think it keeps the connection

Comment: I only found several usages of  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute for sql queries, no other methods described in provided or related links.